# C - Array cant use variable for index

Tags: c, arrays, propeller-tool

I'm having a problem using a variable as an index for an array. The code is basically this:

```
int index;
void main() {
    index = 1;
    doStuff();
}
void doStuff() {
    char** myArray;
    myArray[0] = (char*)"Foo";
    myArray[1] = (char*)"Bar";
    print("%s", myArray[index]);
}
```

Now if I do:

```
print("%s", myArray[1]);
```

It works fine. Could anyone help me out?

It should just be C code, but in the event that it matters, its for a Parallax chip, and I'm using Simple IDE.

Comment: you didnt pass the `index` variable to `doStuff` function

Comment: @Rocker: I thought so, too, at first; but `index` is declared at file scope.

Comment: @Sugitime: What's the error you get?

Comment: `index` is a built in function. Better use another name; `Index` or something. Also, you have a problem, because you're using myArray[0] and myArray[1] before allocating them.

Comment: So I dont get an error. Unfortunately when programming with Parallax, you can't really get the errors real time. The output is just blank.

Comment: Maybe it "works" with a literal `1` due to optimizations. The compiler replaces `myArray[1]` with `"Bar"` in the `printf` (typo?) call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array

```
char** myArray;
```

is not really an array. It is a pointer. Until you assign it, it points nowhere. Any dereferences of it produce undefined behavior.

Dereferencing the undefined pointer is precisely what you do here:

```
myArray[0] = (char*)"Foo";
```

Since the pointer does not point to a valid block of memory, this does not work. What you need to do to make it work is assign `myArray` first. For example, you could do it with `malloc`:

```
char** myArray = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
```

Your code is going to work now. In order to avoid memory leaks, add `free(myArray)` to the end of `doStuff` function.

Comment: Oh god I love you so much. If you were at Defcon, I'd buy you a beer.

Comment: It's interesting that this is the solution, because when I try compiling the source, I definitely get an error saying that you can't redefine the built in function `index`.

Comment: @MrLister: Theoretically, this must be possible as long as you don't include `<strings.h>` (or whatever header you have an `index` function in). Still bad style, of course.

Comment: @mafso No includes. I get `warning: built-in function ‘index’ declared as non-function [enabled by default]` even if I have `int index;` as the only line in my source.

Comment: @MrLister: I get the warning with gcc for `-std=gnu89` and `-std=gnu99` but not for `-std=c89` or `-std=c99`. I also get warnings for ISO C function names (like a file consisting only of `int strchr;`) with `-std=c89` and `-std=c99`. All warnings don't become errors with `-pedantic` and compile successfully. They are always errors if a corresponding header is included. Seems to be a warning against bad practices, not a hard error.

Answer (score -1):

(You need to fix the code: the array `myArray` has not been allocated)

The symbol `index` is already been used by your compiler suite (for example, a function called `index()` in `string.h`). If you change it to "my_index", it will work properly.

A second option is to make the symbol "index" a file-scope variable by making it `static`.

`static int index;`