# Whenever i use index as global variable i get an error

Tags: c, function

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    long int ntc;

    int convnum[64];
    int base;
    int index=0;

    void getnumbase(void)
    {
        printf("enter number\n");   
        scanf("%li",&ntc);
        do
        {   
            printf("enter base\n");
            scanf("%i",&base);
        }
        while(base<2||base>16);
    }

    void convert(void)
    {
        do
        {

          convnum[index]=ntc%base;

          index++;

          ntc/=base;

        }   
        while(ntc!=0);
}

void display(void)
{
    char ch[16]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    int result;

    printf("converted number is \n");


    for(--index;index>=0;index--)
    {
      result=convnum[index];
      printf("%c",ch[result]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}


    main()
{

    getnumbase();

    convert();

    display();

    return 0;

}
```

and this is the error i get: 49.c:6:5: warning: built-in function ‘index’ declared as non-function [enabled by default]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to correct formatting, and to give us the complete error message (which is actually a warning,and but an error)?

Comment: As I believe that great philosopher Grouchy Marx said, *don't do that then*.

Comment: How can you read code when it's formatted in this manner?

Comment: You should also tell us which compiler (name _and version_) you are using, and on what platform...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227840

Comment: What other warnings?

Comment: @AndrewMedico having a variable of the same name doesn't make it a duplicate

Comment: I read in a few other comments, how to know if the name is built-in or predefined. A simple way is to do a `man` on it. Like `man index`.

Answer (score 3):

change this line:

```
int index=0;
```

to this

```
int myIndex=0;
```

and then change all references to your global `index` to `myIndex` in the rest of the code.

Your variable name "index" is conflicting with a library function which is already defined.  By using a different name you can solve the problem.

Comment: You should explain _why_, if you want to be helpful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I tried to... but it seems so obvious to me I'm sure my explanation is bad.  Feel free to improve it LRiO

Comment: It's better now. Still, which library function is that? I can't seem to find any reference to it. Could it be unique to the OP's implementation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it isn't a built in I've heard of -- **but warning messages never lie** :)

Comment: The only `index` function I'm aware of is [the POSIX one](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/index.html), but that's declared in `<strings.h>`, which the OP didn't include.

Comment: >I'm using gcc compiler and ubuntu 64 bit.So is index keyword reserved?

Comment: `index`, `rindex`, `bcopy`, `bzero`, and `bcmp` (and probably a few more that I forget) are ancient BSD functions which used to be in `<string.h>` but didn't make the cut when C was standardized. In standard C the `index` function is gone. In POSIX it was moved to `<strings.h>` for a while but [in the latest version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/strings.h.html) it's gone from there too. However, gcc's default mode is not "standard C" or "standard C with POSIX". It's "compatible with ancient BSD". To compile more modern code, use `-std=c11` (or `c99` or `-ansi`)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke your compiler in standard mode. In standard C you're allowed to have a global variable called `index`. For gcc the switch to use is `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Also this will warn about your old-style declaration of main:

```
main()
```

It should be `int main(void)` .

NB. Of course, it'd be better to refactor your code so that it does not need to use global variables in this way!

Comment: Calling the variable something other than `index` isn't a bad idea.

Comment: using anything else other than index worked fine but wanted to know what the warning was all about.